# Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've written a singly linked list in C++. Would appreciate reviews on code efficiency and best practices.

```
#ifndef SLIST_HPP
#define SLIST_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct node{
    node(T data):data(data),next(nullptr){}
    T data;
    node<T> * next;
};

template< typename T> class slist{
    node<T>* head;
    int size;
public:
    slist(node<T>* head):head(head), size(0){}

    slist(const slist<T>& rhs){

     node<T>* temp = rhs.getHead();

    node<T>* current = new node<T>(temp->data);
    while(temp != nullptr){

        current->next = new node<T>(temp->next->data);
        temp = temp->next;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
    ~slist(){
        if(head == nullptr) return;

        while(head != nullptr){
            node<T>* current = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete(current);
        }
    }
    slist& operator= (const slist& rhs){

    node<T>* temp = rhs.getHead();
    try{
        if(temp == nullptr) throw std::runtime_error("Can't assign null");
    }catch(std::runtime_error& e){
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }

    node<T>* current = head;
    while(temp != nullptr){

        temp = temp->next;
        current = current->next;
        current->next = new node<T>(temp->next->data);
    }


}
    node<T>* getHead()const {
        return head;
    }

    void add(node<T>* p, T item){
        if(p == nullptr) return;
        node<T>* current = new node<T>(item);
        node<T>* temp = p->next;
        p->next = current;
        current->next = temp;
        size++;

    }
    void insertFront(T item){
        node<T>* p = new node<T>(item);
        if(head == nullptr){
            p = head;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        p->next = head;
        head = p;
        size++;
    }

    void insertBack(T item){
        node<T>* p = new node<T>(item);
        node<T>* current = head;
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = p;
        size++;
    }

    void remove(T item){
        bool check = false;

        node<T>* current = head;
        try {
            while(current != nullptr){
                if(current->data == item) check = true;
                current = current->next;
            }
            if(!check){
                throw std::runtime_error("Item not in list");

            }
        }catch(std::runtime_error& e){
            std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }

        current = head;
        while(current != nullptr){
           if(current->next->data == item){
               node<T>* temp = current->next;
               current->next = current->next->next;
               delete(temp);
               break;
           }
            current = current->next;
        }
        size--;

    }
    int getSize () const {
        return size;
    }

    void printList(){
        node<T>* current = head;
        while(current != nullptr){
            if(current->next != nullptr){
                std::cout<<current->data<<"->";
            }else{
                std::cout<<current->data<<std::endl;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};
#endif //SLIST_HPP
```

Comment: I'll be delighted to review your code the moment it works... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72acde890732346b

Comment: The code is tested and it works atleast on my machine.

Comment: I've added the assignment operator and modified the copy constructor, if that is what you're talking about. That aside the code works fine.

Comment: Clearly there's something wrong with your compiler which says that there's no member cout or endl in std.

Comment: @Antithesis No, I don't know how it's working for you when you haven't included the `<iostream>` header.

Comment: Nope, that compiler is working fine. As long as you don't include the header for it, those symbols need not be there. Now it is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b3c652561d9cbe9

Comment: Oops, that's a copy paste error, but I apologize.

Comment: At the cost of reiteration, the copy constructor and assignment operator has been modified, from the original post. That has been done, since there are no answers yet.

Comment: Well, ping us when it works, and is formatted as you want it.

Comment: Done, works fine now.

Comment: Nope, still broken: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b3c652561d9cbe9 FTFY

Answer (score 3):

You're [reimplementing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) `std::forward_list`, so a good place to start would be [the API documentation for `forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). That'll show you a lot of deficiencies in your current approach:

- Naming. For example, `getSize()` should be `size()`, so that you can write generic algorithms that work with your class *in addition to* `std::list`, `std::vector`, etc (all of which have a `size()` method).
- Encapsulation. You provide a public member function `getHead()` that returns a raw pointer to an internal `node`. What do you expect the user to be able to do with a `node<T>*`?
- Composability. Your `remove` member function causes an `exit(-1)` on failure. It would be much much better to have `remove` throw an exception, and then allow the caller to catch and handle the exception — possibly with an `exit`, but possibly in some other way.
- Support common C++ idioms. Your list class doesn't provide `begin()` and `end()`, so it's not iterable; e.g. I can't say `for (auto&& element : myList) { std::cout << element; }`. If you provide iteration, then I can write this loop, so I won't need your `printList` member function anymore.

Finally, one more naming nit: As a member function, `printList` could just be named `print`. `myList.print()` is slightly better (shorter and [less repetitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) than `myList.printList()`. And again it enables generic programming:

```
// You could overload this printTwice function for each container type:

void printTwice(const List& l)
{
    l.printList();
    l.printList();
}

void printTwice(const Vector& l)
{
    l.printVector();
    l.printVector();
}

// ^ But yuck. Prefer genericity:

template<class Container>
void printTwice(const Container& c)
{
    c.print();
    c.print();
}

// ^ In fact, prefer to use non-member functions for anything that
// doesn't require special access to the innards of the class:

template<class Container>
void printTwice(const Container& c)
{
    print(c);
    print(c);
}

// ^ In fact, prefer to spell the verb "print" in the standard way[*]:

template<class Container>
void printTwice(const Container& c)
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

[* – unless you're really concerned about efficiency, in which case you should probably stay away from iostreams; but at that point you're not doing generic programming anymore anyway]